# .htaccess to limit access to directory not working properly

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to limit access to a directory based on the results of a php script.  I have the following in my .htaccess folder where the files are located:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=league_access.php
RewriteRule .* league_access.php
```

I have also tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* league_access.php
```

If you go to the directory http://www.bowling-tracker.com/bowl/league_documents/1/ you will note that it is firing the league_access.php script (as it currently only types "Running the Test Script
Restricted access" to the page.

So that is acting correctly.

http://www.bowling-tracker.com/bowl/league_documents/1/test.html you will see that you're granted access to the page (rather than it going to the league_access.php script).

This website is on FastComet (public hosting company) so I cannot change server settings or files except the .htaccess file.

Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FastComet Team here! Part of our shared hosting environment is utilizing NginX as a reverse proxy to the Apache web service. This configuration gets the advantages of both services at the same time and ensures a better performance of your project. NginX is processing all requests for static content, such as PDF files or HTML pages. Here's a list of all file types that will be processed by the NginX service:

3gp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|avi|asf|asx|mpg|mpeg|mp4|pls|mp3|mid|wav|swf|flv|html|htm|js|css|exe|zip|tar|rar|gz|tgz|bz2|uha|7z|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|iso

However, if the request is for dynamic content, such as a PHP script, it will be passed from the NginX to the Apache service. You are correctly setting the rule in question in the .htaccess file of your website, but this file is only read by the Apache service, not NginX. In other words, if there is a request for a static content, such as a PDF file here:

> http://www.bowling-tracker.com/bowl/league_documents/1/Rules_Thurs_Night_Mixed.pdf

or an HTML page here:

> http://www.bowling-tracker.com/bowl/league_documents/1/test.html

it will be processed by NginX without considering the .htaccess rules that you have set. There is an easy way of resolving that by excluding the processing of HTML, HTM and PDF types files for your domain or even your entire hosting account. This way, those requests will be processed by the Apache web server, instead of NginX. In this case, the .htaccess rules that you apply will be taken into consideration by the system and they will work without any issues.

Comment: And how would I "exclude the processing of PDF file types on the domain"?

Comment: For your convenience, our Technical support team has already excluded the HTML, HTM and PDF types from processing by the NginX service for your bowling-tracker.com domain name. This way, they are passed directly to Apache and the rules that you have set in .htaccess will be applied properly. If you would like us to exclude another file type, or apply the same changes to another domain name on your hosting account, you can simply submit a ticket to our Technical Support team and we would be happy to take care of that for you.